# Symfon2 database record inserion

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a problem with symfony2 record insertion
My requirement is to find out all the users who are in between particular ages and the given column is dob. 
I am getting the result with this mysql query.

```
SELECT * FROM app_users WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dob) BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

How to rewrite this query in the symfony- doctrine fromat?
Pls help...

Comment: `YEAR(CURDATE())` return `yyyy` not `yy`

Answer (score 0):

```
     $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
     $qb->select('au')
        ->from('AppUsers au)
        ->where($qb->expr()->between('YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(au.dob)', 10,20));
     $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I have not checked it. but it may help you.